# input type ="url" for relative URLs

Tags: html, input

I had a input box for users to enter in a custom link to a page from the creation form (somewhat similar to Wordpress).  (e.g. `about/awards` which gets used for `http://site.com/pages/about/awards` ) At some point, this stopped working in Chrome, as they now do stricter validation of `input type="url"` field. Which would be good but:

- It doesn't allow relative urls. about/awards is a relative URL, but Chrome seems to reject everything except absolute URLs http://domain/page/stuff
- The failure isn't particularly obvious. It just focuses on the form field (which isn't particularly noticeable), and refuses to submit the form. The report I got was that the form "doesn't work", as they didn't notice what was going on, and it took me a few minutes to realise what is going on.

I've fixed it by just switching back to input type="text" but this defeats some of the useful stuff that `type="url"` added (such as the special keyboard on the iPhone).

Is this a part of the HTML5 spec, or a problem in Chrome's implementation?

Comment: @GSto: My bad, forgot the most important sentence.

Comment: You could prepend the relative URL with "http://" on submit to make it valid.  See examples here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946960/with-html5-url-input-validation-assume-url-starts-with-http/41193579#41193579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says, "While the value of the element is not a valid absolute URL, the element is suffering from a type mismatch."

Answer (score 2):

The spec is still being worked on, but from this quote, it sounds like it could be an issue with Chrome's implementation (bold emphasis is mine):

> **User agents may allow the user to set
>   the value to a string that is not a
>   valid absolute URL**, but may also or
>   instead automatically escape
>   characters entered by the user so that
>   the value is always a valid absolute
>   URL (even if that isn't the actual
>   value seen and edited by the user in
>   the interface). User agents should
>   allow the user to set the value to the
>   empty string. User agents must not
>   allow users to insert U+000A LINE FEED
>   (LF) or U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)
>   characters into the value.

[Source](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#url-state)

Answer (score 2):

A plausable still *semantic* workaround that I am using is to allow relative URLs using the `pattern` attribute:

```
<input required="required" type="url" pattern="(https?|/).*?" name="sStyleBackgroundImageURL" value="{!sStyleBackgroundImageURL}"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers do not allow validation to succeed when relative urls are entered. Instead set the input pattern attribute to a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a pattern for unallowed characters something like the following:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[^\<\>\^\`\{\|\}\r\n\t\f\v]*" placeholder="Your Relative or Absolute Path">
```

Enjoy...