# HTML5 url type input protocol requirements

Tags: html, input

Currently, if I have `<input type="url">`, someone adding a URL without the protocol will cause a message to appear, saying "Please enter a URL". Is it possible to assume http://, unless otherwise specified? If that requires the use of Javascript, or something overly complicated, is there a way to keep the url type on the input, without it stopping someone from completing the form?

Comment: Check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946960/with-html5-url-input-validation-assume-url-starts-with-http

Comment: So my choices are to use a script, which is out of the question for me, or to use an attribute that won't have the same effects across all browsers? I think I'll just turn the url field into a normal text field, then.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of `<input type="url">` varies by browser. It can be implemented as a gadget that implies `http://` at the start when no protocol part is present, or in some other way.

You can use the attribute `value="http://"` to specify an initial value, probably helping the user to get the URL syntactically right. But this is suitable for *required* fields only. Since `http://` is not a valid URL (just a prefix), constraint validation will report an error, if the user does not change the initial value – which is fine for a required field, but not for an optional field.